# React Native - Derectional Pad support Android TV App

Tags: react-native, d-pad

I would want to build an Android TV app using React-Native. I have followed up the recommendation on this document: [Building For TV Devices](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv).

After, update the AndroidManifest.xml file I run the application using the command line - react-native run android. The app running without any issue; however, I tried to use the Directional-pad option from android emulator TV (720p) API 23 emulator and it didn't work. I was expecting to catch the event listed on the code below and write to the console respective test for each event. On the other hand, even the component that was used for text didn't get highlighted either focus on when I try to navigate using Directional-pad.

I am reaching out to the community to see if someone had this issue in the past and what was your issue and what you have done to resolve it? Also, as I am listing the steps below, if you could let me know if I missing something?

Please, let me know if you need any extra information in order to help me.

1. react-native init Dpad
2. cd Dpad
3. Update code based on - [Building For
   TV Devices](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv)
4. Start Android TV (720p) API 23 emulator.
5. react-native run-android

ANNEX:
[Android TV (720p) API 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7J3.png)

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Channel from '../channel/channel.component';
import styles from './presentation.component.styles';

var TVEventHandler = require('TVEventHandler');

export default class Grid extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         command: 'undefined'
      }
    }

    setcomand( command) {
      this.setState( () => { return { command: command }; });
    }

    _tvEventHandler: null;
    _enableTVEventHandler() {
        this._tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
        this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function(cmp, evt) {
          if (evt && evt.eventType === 'right') {
            setcomand('Press Right!');
          } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'up') {
            setcomand('Press Up!');
          } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'left') {
            setcomand('Press Left!');
          } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'down') {
            setcomand('Press Down!');
          } 
        });
    }  

    _disableTVEventHandler() {
        if (this._tvEventHandler) {
          this._tvEventHandler.disable();
          delete this._tvEventHandler;
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._enableTVEventHandler();
        console.warn("component did mount");
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this._disableTVEventHandler();
        console.warn("component Will Unmount");
      }

    render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.command}</Text>
            <Channel name="Globo" description="Its brazilian TV channles for news"/>
            <Channel name="TVI" description="Its Portuguese TV channles for news"/>
            <Channel name="TVI" description="Its Portuguese TV channles for news"/>
        </View>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you not able to test? are you getting an error? you need to give more information

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: It is not enough to drop "what I want" + "my current code". You have to clearly explain what kind of problem you have with your code!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also struggling with this problem for a month. Still can't find help/solution.
I testing this on Android Studio Emulator and also on few real android TV boxes with real remote d-pads.
I still can't figure out if it's React Native problem (bug) or Android TV devices don't emit response (keyCode) on directional d-pad arrows.
I can reproduce events like: focus, blur, select, fastForward, playPause, rewind, but no way to get events like e.g. "left".
I search a lot of google and other sites, you are first one who struggling with same issue.
I feel like no one cares about Android TV in React-Native.
You can also comment my Issue thread on React-Native github page.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20924
I hope we figure it out soon.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to verify that Directional-pad works with react-native. That was my goal of this demo. I am learning to build android Tv using react-native and so far Directional-pad it's being a big challenge given that TV user won't use touch screen event.

However, I couldn't find out why my app was not responding to the Directional-pad keyboard (left, right, up and down). There was no code error.

Have you tried to use Directional-pad to navigate on your react-native app?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Dave -

I decided to develop Android TV app using React Native because the video that react-native team shared - [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzIQErHhY20] and the tutorial page [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv]. I think that's everything we have; other than that we won't get further support.

***GOOD NEWS***  - I have started a new project from scratch using **react native version 0.57.0**, **node version V10.7.not and **npm Version 4.6.1**. Also, for navigation, I am using react-navigation version 2. I was able to see that my Directional-pad emulator was working, however, I was not able to see the focus on the element that I am navigating (left, right, down, up).

I will be working to see how I can fix the focus issue.
Let's keeping share our progress and feel free to reach out.

Thank you,

Justimiano Alves

Comment: Just create your own UI components that wrap TouchableHighlight and implement onBlur and onFocus. You can set focused state on the components and render focused state for each component as they become focused and blurred. Some examples would be adding a border to a teaser card or colorizing a list item in a menu drawer. My biggest issue now is handling   scrollTo on list views so the item in focus on a grid is always in the upper left corner of the grid (i.e. Netflix and YouTube 2018 UI).

Answer (score 1):

```
use this code and u can see the console on debugger



_tvEventHandler: any;


_enableTVEventHandler() {
        var self = this;
        this._tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
        this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function (cmp, evt) {
            console.log("kcubsj"+evt.eventType)
            if (evt && evt.eventType === 'right') {
                console.log('right');
            } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'up') {
                console.log('up');
            } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'left') {
                console.log('left');
            } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'down') {
                console.log('down');
            } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'select') {
                //self.press();
            }
        });
    }

_disableTVEventHandler() {
        if (this._tvEventHandler) {
            this._tvEventHandler.disable();
            delete this._tvEventHandler;
        }
    }

 componentDidMount() {
        this._enableTVEventHandler();
    }

componentWillUnmount() {
        this._disableTVEventHandler();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have really good news about support for D-Pad arrow events (up, down, left, right).
It turned out that one of Android TV contributor for react-native is person from my country. I reach out contact with him and tell about this problem. He check that out and actually, there is missing code for that.
He made pull request to support that in react-native. It should be fixed in one of upcoming new version releases (he said it might took about month).
Temporarly I know how to handle this (add code and recompile java files), I already tested it and its work great. All events now working. If you really need that support now and don't want to wait, I can share how to do that.

Cheers

Comment: Dave - I was able to install my app on Android TV and the D-Pad worked fine. However, I would like you to join me and build the community around building ios & android app using react native. 

React Native TV Group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/reactnativetv/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I would like to see your solution because I am able to navigate using the D-pad but I couldn't see which element I am navigating to. I need to highlight or show focus on the element that I navigating to.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm struggling with highlighting a selected item in a flatlist

Answer (score 0):

Having `console.log` inside the TVEventHandler callback seems to break it when running without remote js debugger on.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that D-pad does not work if there is no focusable component. To solve this, I have placed a transparent touchable opacity component on my screen. After that D-pad started working. My code for D-pad key event is given below:

```
enableTVEventHandler() {
  this.tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
  this.tvEventHandler.enable(this, (cmp, { eventType, eventKeyAction }) => {

  // eventKeyAction is an integer value representing button press(key down) and release(key up). "key up" is 1, "key down" is 0.

  if (eventType === 'playPause' && eventKeyAction === 0)
  {
    console.log('play pressed')
  }
  else if(eventType === 'fastForward'  && eventKeyAction === 0){
    console.log('forward pressed')
  }
  else if (eventType === 'rewind'  && eventKeyAction === 0){
    console.log('rewind pressed')
  }
  else if (eventType === 'select'  && eventKeyAction === 0)
  {
   console.log('select pressed')
  }else if(eventType === 'left'  && eventKeyAction === 0){
    console.log('left pressed')
  }
  else if(eventType === 'right'  && eventKeyAction === 0){
    console.log('right pressed')
  }
  else if(eventType === 'up' && eventKeyAction === 0){
        console.log('up pressed')
  }
  else if(eventType === 'down' && eventKeyAction === 0){
        console.log('down pressed')
  }
  });
```

}